# Как связать данные нескольких столбцов и вставить их в новый столбец одной и той же таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица где есть данные, но теперь нужно добавить новый столбец (я отдельно добавил ее - new_column) и в нее вставить запись собранной из других столбцов той же таблицы,  пытался сделать так но не работает:

insert into table t
(new_column)

select (column_1 || '-' || column_2 || '-' || column_3 || '-' || column_4) nc from table;

commit;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком случае, лучше всего, подходит вычисляемый столбец:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD (nc varchar(512) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (column_1 || '-' || column_2 || '-' || column_3 || '-' || column_4) VIRTUAL);
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

варианты:

1. буквальный:

   ```
   update t set new_column= column_1 || '-' || column_2 || '-' || column_3 || '-' || column_4
   ```
2. почему бы не использовать вьюшку?  вида:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW new_t as
   select 
     t.*,
     column_1 || '-' || column_2 || '-' || column_3 || '-' || column_4 as new_column  
   from t
   ```